# How to create the Kubernetes Dashboard by using Kubeadm methods?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

Unable to create the Kubernetes Dashboard

I have setup my Kubernetes cluster by using Kubeadm in google cloud platform. I have followed https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard docs for creating the Kubernetes Dashboard, but I am unable to create the same.

Please let me know how to create the Kubernetes Dashboard in Kubeadm method.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Installation

kubectl create secret generic kubernetes-dashboard-certs --from-file=$HOME/certs -n kube-system
(your certs need to be in the home directory)

kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v1.10.1/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml

Then grant privileges as you see fit...

Comment: also this will walk through access control https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Access-control
once dashboard is installed.

Comment: I have followed the above steps and created dashboard container on kubernetes cluster(Google cloud platform env), still I unable to get the kubernetes dashboard. But it working fine in vm's env. Please let me know how to create the kubernetes dashboard on Google cloud platform env.